# Flex 4 move all TitleWindows instances within the visible area after application change it's width/height?

Tags: apache-flex, scale

- Is there a nice and not much processor consuming way to move all TitleWindow instances within the application visible area when the application been scaled - change it's width or height ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `systemManager`'s `resize` event and then iterate all the pop ups the following way (in resize handler):

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < systemManager.popUpChildren.numChildren; i++)
{
    var popup:DisplayObject = systemManager.popUpChildren. getChildAt(i);
    if (popup is TitleWindow)
    {
        var window:TitleWindow = TitleWindow(popup);
        // Your move operations here
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work. :| `systemManager.addEventListener( Event.RESIZE, onSystemManagerResize ); private function onSystemManagerResize( e : Event ) : void
   {
    for( var i:int = 0; i < systemManager.popUpChildren.numChildren; i++ )
    {
     var popup : DisplayObject = systemManager.popUpChildren.getChildAt( i );
     
     if( popup is TitleWindow )
     {
      Alert.show( "D" );
      var window : TitleWindow = TitleWindow( popup );
      if( ( window.x + window.width ) > width )
       window.x = width - window.width;
     }
    }
   }

Comment: Subscribe to Application's resize. The code I gave is just an idea. Please add your own individuality there :)

Comment: couldn't find a way to check all of the instances with systemManager :| Any other suggestions ?

Comment: What's the difficulty? What step you can't reproduce?

Comment: i have extend from TitleWindow class, which handle all of the things i must overwatch. and i am checking with "if( popup is MyTitleWindowClass ){ ... } but it never trigering.

Comment: What never triggering? The method with your `if` or `if` itself? Do you able to use Flash Builder's debugger?

Comment: nope. i dont know why i can not use the debugger. i am setting break points but they never triggering.

Comment: Please read [this documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7f07.html).

Comment: successfully running for a very first time the debuger. ... "my prescious" ... "my prescious" ... :D Thank You.